# how can I change keyup functions to click functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that makes submission using keyup functions. please how do I change the keyup function to click.

i have tried `$('#btn').on('click',function(e){`
but cannot get it to work.

below is the keyup function with javascript.

```
$(function(){


//$('#btn').on('click',function(e){


 $('#username').on('keyup',function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if(e.which === 13){
            var name = $this.val();
            socket.emit('new user', name, function(response){
                if(response){
                    localStorage.setItem('username',name);
                    $this.val('');
                    $('#userinfo').hide();
                    $('#chat-body').fadeIn();

alert(name);    

                    loadMessages(); //retrieve messages from Database
                } else{
                    $('.validation').text('Username taken!').fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
    });


});
```

For Html I have this

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="type your name and press enter">
```

below is the click button am trying to add

```
<button type="button" id="btn">send</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: replace .change with .click

Comment: @MuhamamdUsman FYI, `$.fn.on` does the same to add event listeners

Comment: Note that the checks on `event.which` would also need to be changed

Comment: Hey, there's no `'keyup'` event. `'change'` event only fires when input is modified and when the blur event fires, and the input can't be only changed through the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to remove the `e.which === 13` condition, which is breaking the next instructions to execute in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#username").keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
         {
            var name = $this.val();
            alert("ciao");

         }
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rtqw3ovr/)

However, I would not emit an event for every digit enetered by the user, in order to not congestion broker server. I would "wait" for some second before firing an event.

Comment: I want to use a click function not keyup. something like this $('#btn').on('click',function(){

Comment: your goal is not clear. Adding a click to an input to get the same functionalities of keyup sounds to me a littel strange